# How to find Max Daily Sold and Average Daily Sold in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that records daily sales. Sample data is as follows. Please help me with the formula in E4 to E5 (maximum daily count of a particular SKU) and F4 to F5 (average daily count of a particular SKU).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest nested queries like this:

```
=query(
QUERY(A:B,"SELECT B,COUNT(A) where A is not null GROUP BY A,B"),
"select Col1,max(Col2),avg(Col2) group by Col1 label max(Col2) 'Max of daily sold',avg(Col2) 'Average of daily sold'")
```

[image]

Note: this agrees with OP's results, but average is only calculated over days where there has been a sale of a particular item, so the correct result for Item_A  should (I think) be 1.5.

*EDIT*

If the SKU's were prefilled in (say) D1:D3, you could use a lookup to get the values from the nested queries:

```
=ArrayFormula(
vlookup(D1:D3,query(
QUERY(A:B,"SELECT B,COUNT(A) where A is not null GROUP BY A,B"),
"select Col1,max(Col2),avg(Col2) group by Col1 label max(Col2) 'Max of daily sold',avg(Col2) 'Average of daily sold'"),{2,3},false))
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This is what I am looking for. However, how to write the query if Column D (SKU) is fixed value. Meaning the SKU already pre-filled in column D. The query should be on cell E1 with generated data for "Max daily sold" and "Average daily sold" matching to the SKU on its respective rows?

Comment: thanks! this is perfect!